# Trying fsolve from many initial points

Tags: matlab, optimization

I just checked that it may be the case that fsolve succeeds under a certain initial value but fails under another, as can be seen in the following example.

[image]

So I wanted to create a new function like fsolve2 which goes like this:

1. Try with x0
2. Then if exitflag looks not good, try with another.
3. Do it until exitflag looks good. Terminate if it exceeds some number of tries.

But I am not sure about the best way to set the next initial value when the previous one failed. I could just try random initial values. I could try grid. But that's not a "smart" way to do it. How would you wisely choose some initial value?

Is there already some Matlab option or command which does this?

Comment: It really depends on what your `fune_solve` function is. Generating good initial guesses is generally a hard problem.

Comment: As @edwinksl indicates, there is no universal way of picking good starting points - if there was then it would be implemented in the `fsolve` algorithm itself.  If you have the `Global Optimization Toolbox` then you can use the [Multistart Class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/multistart-class.html) to automatically check multiple different starting points in a convenient way.